# MapDispatchToProps returns a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to read my articles from my firebase DB but I can't make it work.

Here is my DB:

```
myDB-myid
  articles
    1
     body: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor si damet blablabla"
     createdAt: 12345
     subtitle: "ça promet beaucoup d'autres supers articles"
     title: "Mon premier article"
    2
     body: "Encore du Lorem Ipsum et bla et bla et bla..."
     createdAt: 34567
    subtitle: "Vous avez aimé le premier ? Le deuxième va vous..."
     title: "Et voici le deuxième article"
```

my component that should render the list of all articles, `ArticlePage`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Article from './Article';
import { startSetArticles } from '../../actions/articles';

const ArticlesPage = props => (
      <div className="articles-wrapper">
        <div className="container">
        {console.log(props.articles)}
        {
          props.articles.length === 0 ? (
            <p>No article</p>
            ) : (
            props.articles.map(a => {
              return <Article key={a.id} {...a}/>
            })
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
      );

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  articles: () => dispatch(startSetArticles())
});

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticlesPage);
```

my store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import authReducer from '../reducers/auth';
import articlesReducer from '../reducers/articles';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      auth: authReducer,
      articles: articlesReducer
    }),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );

  return store;
};
```

my actions in `action/articles.js`:

```
import database from '../firebase/firebase';

// SET_ARTICLES
export const setArticles = articles => ({
  type: 'SET_ARTICLES',
  articles
});

export const startSetArticles = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return database.ref('articles').once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const articles = [];

      snapshot.forEach(a => {
        articles.push({
          id: a.key,
          ...a.val()
        });
      });
      dispatch(setArticles(articles));
    });
  };
};
```

my reducer in `reducers/articles.js`:

```
const articlesReducerDefaultState = [];

export default (state = articlesReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_ARTICLES':
        return action.articles;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But I can't make it work. Here is the console output of the `console.log(props.articles)` from the component:

```
ƒ articles() {
      return dispatch((0, _articles.startSetArticles)());
    }
```

Any Idea ? It should render the two posts but it only returns the function itself. (I get a 'no article' from the ternary operator)

Comment: If you want to access some of your state, you should use mapStateToProps. mapDispatchToProps is meant to be use to dispatch an action ( something like fetchArticles in your article maybe).

Comment: 1) `articles` from `mapDispatchToProps` overrides `arcticles` from the store (which is not even mapped to components props); 2) `startSetArticles` is not called anywhere

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers; I see where the problem is but even once I added mapStateToProps, It does not fetch my data from firebase. How can I do this ? (sorry; Im quite new to redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`articles` is a function because that's exactly what you do:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  articles: () => dispatch(startSetArticles())
});
```

you **map dispatch to props** and you mapped it to a prop called `articles` which is a function that dispatches an action. No surprise here. But I guess what you also want is to **map state to props** which you can do with a first argument of connect:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ articlesList: state.articles });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticlesPage);
```

Now if you do `console.log(props)` you should get Object with two properties:

```
{
  articles, // a function from mapDispatchToProps
  articlesList // a function from mapStateToProps 
}
```

**EDIT:**

You still however need to call your articles function to fetch data with firebase and populate the redux store. Best way to start asynchronous data is to use componentDidMount() hook:

```
class ArticlesPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.articles();  // use mapped function to dispatch redux action
  }

  render() {
    // render data with array from the store
    return (
      <div className="articles-wrapper">
        <div className="container">
          {this.props.articlesList.length === 0 ? (
            <p>No article</p>
          ) : (
            this.props.articlesList.map(a => {
              return <Article key={a.id} {...a} />;
            })
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's right, I added your code and I do get what you said, thank you. However, I am new to Redux and I'm trying to fetch the two articles in my DB; here both objects articles and articlesList are empty. How can I solve this ?

Comment: I still don't really get the thing with states and dispatchs, but your edit works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help Tomasz !

Comment: @JulesCorb No problem. Once you get it it's simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you only connected to the store, but never called the function `startSetArticles()`. Try add(this will work with your current mapDispatchToProps)

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.articles()
  }
```

This should call the function, which should update your store.

And I would recommend instead of:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  articles: () => dispatch(startSetArticles())
});
```

You should just do this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  startSetArticles: () => dispatch(startSetArticles())
});
```

Then you would have to do this, which makes more sense.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.startSetArticles()
  }
```

I think your confusion is about how to use `mapDispatchToProps`. When you mapDispatchToProps, it `DOES NOT` call that function right away. You will still need to call that function somewhere in the component. In your case `componenetDidMount` makes sense.

And then you need to add `mapStateToProps`, which will connect to the store and actually get the data back.

Here is a working example:

```
export class Morphology extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = 'Eflows | Morphology';
    this.props.fetchGeoSites();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={styles.banner} />
        <Layout geoSites={this.props.geoSites} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Morphology.propTypes = {
  fetchGeoSites: PropTypes.func,
  geoSites: PropTypes.array,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    geoSites: state.geoSite.geoSites,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchGeoSites: () => dispatch(fetchGeoSites()),
  };
};
```

I am using the same method, you can look into it more with this repo:
https://github.com/leogoesger/eflow-client

Answer (score 0):

You should use the first parameter of `connect` to get the `articles` state.

```
connect(state => ({ articles: state.articles }), ...)
```

To set the `articles` state, you need to call `startSetArticles` somewhere like `componentDidMount` or in the file where you declare your `store` (if you want it to be called when the app loads) with `store.dispatch(startSetArticles())`.

Comment: store.dispatch looks like a bad idea, the point of mapDispatchToProps is to avoid accessing directly the store

Comment: @Axnyff Depends on the use case. If the action creator populates a state that is used by multiple components/routes, then calling it in the file where `store` is declared (or some other file) makes more sense than calling it in every route/component.